# iBATIS - Defining 'javaType' and 'jdbcType'

Tags: java, ibatis

While defining the `resultMap` in iBatis, it provides an option to set the `javaType` and `jdbcType` for each property to column mapping.

e.g.

```
<resultMap id="employee" class="com.mycompany.Employee">
   <result property="firstName" column="first_name" javaType="?" jdbcType="?"/>
</resultMap>
```

**Wanted to know that when we should be defining the `javaType` and `jdbcType`?** I have seen mapping where it *just* works without defining these properties and in others we have to define them.

**EDIT:** See the selected answer below for the above question.

**Also, do we have an exhaustive list out of which `javaType` and `jdbcType` should be defined?**

**EDIT:** `javaType` should be one of the well-known types e.g. `java.lang.String`, `java.util.Date`
and `jdbcType` should be coming out of [java.sql.Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `jdbcType` the [documentation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ibatis/java/ibatis-3/trunk/doc/en/iBATIS-3-User-Guide.pdf) (for iBATIS 3) states:

> The JDBC type is only required for nullable columns upon insert, update or delete.

On page 33 in this document is a list of supported JDBC types.

For the `javaType` attribute it says:

> iBATIS can usually figure out the type if you’re mapping to a JavaBean. However, if you are mapping to a HashMap, then you should specify the javaType explicitly to ensure the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Elbonian! This answers when to use javaType and jdbcType properties. For answer to the second question please see the EDIT in question.