# iBatis SQL Mapper Date Argument

Tags: java, ibatis

I'm just new to Spring and I'm a little bit confuse with `iBatis`. I was given a task to edit a select query condition (pretty simple) but things get tricky.
I only pass `java.sql.Date` object (with setter and getter) to the SQLMapper to provide the condition parameter.
This is what my `WHERE` clause looks like

```
<sql id="dateWhere">
    <where>
       <if test="arg.sqlStartDate != null and arg.sqlEndDate != null">
          table.date BETWEEN #{arg.sqlStartDate} AND #{arg.sqlEndDate}
       </if>
    </where>
</sql>
```

But I get an error

`org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='arg.sqlStartDate', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException`

And I researched that I need to specify the `jdbcType` of the argument. [SOlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907055/ibatis-defining-javatype-and-jdbctype). Also added a `DATE()` function to further specify that the argument is a `DATE` variable.

```
 <sql id="dateWhere">
        <where>
           <if test="arg.sqlStartDate != null and arg.sqlEndDate != null">
              table.date BETWEEN DATE(#{arg.sqlStartDate,jdbcType=DATE}) AND DATE(#{arg.sqlEndDate,jdbcType=DATE})
           </if>
        </where>
  </sql>
```

And I got it working. But I notice with other Mapper they didn't specify the `jdbcType` of each argument. So I got confuse on what really is this problem and what cause it, how this happens, what I have done wrong. Just give me information to further understand this matter. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use DATE() function. 
Use java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date and `table.date BETWEEN #{arg.sqlStartDate} AND #{arg.sqlEndDate}` should work.

Apparently iBatis can better handle java.util.Date than java.sql.Date

Comment: Like I said I got an error when did that. For some reason iBatis is cannot identify the `jdbcType` of the `java.util.Date`

Comment: you sohuld use java.util.Date, not java.sql.Date

Comment: Sorry about that, can you explain what is the difference in using `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` as a argument in iBatis sqlMapper?

Comment: It's just a different type. Apparently iBatis can better handle java.util.Date than java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 1):

https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf

Page 26, Section ***jdbcType***

This is due to the inability of the JDBC driver to identify the column type of certain columns automatically.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, so apparently @e.g78 answer was correct but no explicit explanation on why

Comment: @e.g78 You didn't explain why and what